# Want to autobuild a docker image when a third repository is updated

Tags: github, docker, dockerhub

I have a Github repository containing a Dockerfile. Linked to this repository there is a Docker(hub) repository for the autobuilding. The autobuild works fine.
One of the steps of this Dockerfile is to download files from another (third) Github repository: the software to run inside the container.
The question is whether there is a known mechanism for triggering the Docker image when this third repository (containing the application source code, and not the dockerfile) is updated?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Docker Hub, go to your repository and look at "Build Setting" > "Build Triggers". This will give you a URL that accepts POSTs and triggers a build.

Then go to the Github repository that should trigger the build and add that trigger-url under "Settings" > "Webhooks & Services" > "Webhooks" and you can choose when Github POSTs to it (triggering the build).